# Read Rows Sequentially, but On Demand

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

I need to iterate through an Excel spreadsheet row by row, but not all at once. I want to keep a stream open to the spreadsheet, and then pass that object along to another method. This method will ask for the next row of data from time to time. This method is already established, so I can't change it.

I tried doing this initially with `XSSFWorkbook`, which worked really well, until I ran out of memory on real data.

Then I tried switching to the SAX parser, using `XSSFSheetXMLHandler`, with a custom parser similar to the sample one `XLSX2CSV` provided by the Apache POI project. But this results in all rows processing at one time; and if I store them in memory to read later I also run out of memory. I also didn't have access to the `DataFormatter` anymore, which I need for cell value processing.

Can someone point me to an example/class that will allow me to do this?

Comment: With a good example, it would probably be ok. My biggest concern is the cell formatting. `DataFormatter` makes it easy, but on my own in the XML... Need a good example for that too.

Comment: Well, for formatting XML you could use XSLT via the Java Transformer class: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4604497/xslt-processing-with-java

Comment: p.s. this question will also be of use to you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/504689/big-xml-file-and-outofmemoryerror, SAX with the XSLT example I provided above should solve this problem. XSLT is fairly simple, think of it as a stylesheet for XML.

Comment: @MasterYoda Unfortunately the XML option is actually the same as the one I mentioned in my question. It uses a custom handler and processes all rows at once.  I looked at the SAX link you sent, and I do think SAX is the right option. I don't need much context over time, just a few rows of data at once. So far all the SAX examples I've found use handlers and parse the whole sheet at one go.

Answer (score 1):

My preferrred Streaming API for XML is [StAX](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jaxp/stax/why.html).

Knowing that a `*.xlsx` file is simply a `ZIP` archive and `apache poi`s [OPCPackage](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/openxml4j/opc/OPCPackage.html) for this is a `ZipPackage`, we could think about the following approach:

- Get the `/xl/worksheets/sheetN.xml` package part from the  `*.xlsx
  Excel` `ZipPackage`.
- Create a `StAX` reader on it.
- Now we can read from this `XML` using this reader.

The following example creates a rudimentary application which is doing this row by row using a button click.

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

import org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.*;

import javax.xml.stream.*;
import javax.xml.stream.events.*;

import javax.xml.namespace.QName;

import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class GetExcelRowByRow extends JPanel implements ActionListener {
 protected JButton button;
 protected JTextArea textArea;
 private final static String newline = "\n";

 //file path to Excel file and sheet number to work with
 private final static String filepath = "file.xlsx";
 private final static int scheetnr = 1;

 private StaxExcelRowByRowReader reader;

 public GetExcelRowByRow() {
  super(new GridBagLayout());
  button = new JButton("Next Row");
  button.addActionListener(this);
  textArea = new JTextArea(15, 50) {
   @Override
   public boolean getScrollableTracksViewportWidth() {
    return true;
   }
  };
  textArea.setLineWrap(true);
  textArea.setEditable(false);
  JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(textArea);
  GridBagConstraints c = new GridBagConstraints();
  c.gridwidth = GridBagConstraints.REMAINDER;
  c.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
  add(button, c);
  c.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
  c.weightx = 1.0;
  c.weighty = 1.0;
  add(scrollPane, c);

  try {
   reader = new StaxExcelRowByRowReader(filepath, scheetnr);
  } catch (Exception ex) {
   ex.printStackTrace();
  }

 }
 @Override
 public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
  String row = "Row not found...";
  try {
   row = reader.getNextRow();
  } catch (Exception ex) {
   ex.printStackTrace();
  }
  textArea.append(row + newline);
  textArea.setCaretPosition(textArea.getDocument().getLength());
 }

 public StaxExcelRowByRowReader getReader() {
  return reader;
 }

 private static void createAndShowGUI() {
  JFrame frame = new JFrame("Get Excel row by row");
  frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
  GetExcelRowByRow app = new GetExcelRowByRow();
  frame.add(app);

  frame.addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {
   @Override
   public void windowClosing(WindowEvent windowEvent) {
    try {
     app.getReader().close();
    } catch (Exception ex) {
     ex.printStackTrace();
    }
    System.exit(0);
   }
  });

  frame.pack();
  frame.setVisible(true);
 }

 public static void main(String[] args) {
  javax.swing.SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
   public void run() {
    createAndShowGUI();
   }
  });
 }

 //class for reading a /xl/worksheets/sheetN.xml package part from a *.xlsx Excel ZipPackage 
 private class StaxExcelRowByRowReader {

  private XMLEventReader sheetreader;
  private OPCPackage opcpackage; 

  public StaxExcelRowByRowReader(String filepath, int sheetnr) {
   try {
    opcpackage = OPCPackage.open(filepath, PackageAccess.READ);
    //get the sheet package part
    PackagePart sheetpart = opcpackage.getPartsByName(Pattern.compile("/xl/worksheets/sheet"+sheetnr+".xml")).get(0);
    //create reader for the sheet package part            
    sheetreader = XMLInputFactory.newInstance().createXMLEventReader(sheetpart.getInputStream());
   } catch (Exception ex) {
    ex.printStackTrace();
   }
  }

  //method for getting the next row from the reader
  public String getNextRow() throws Exception {
   StringBuffer row = new StringBuffer();
   boolean valueFound = false;
   boolean nextValueIsSharedString = false;
   while(sheetreader.hasNext()){
    XMLEvent event = sheetreader.nextEvent();
    if(event.isStartElement()) {
     StartElement startElement = (StartElement)event;
     QName startElementName = startElement.getName();
     if(startElementName.getLocalPart().equalsIgnoreCase("row")) { //start element of row
      row.append("<row");
      row.append(" " + startElement.getAttributeByName(new QName("r")));
      row.append(">");
     } else if(startElementName.getLocalPart().equalsIgnoreCase("c")) { //start element of cell
      row.append("<c");
      row.append(" " + startElement.getAttributeByName(new QName("r")));
      row.append(" " + startElement.getAttributeByName(new QName("s")));
      row.append(" " + startElement.getAttributeByName(new QName("t")));
      row.append(">");
      Attribute type = startElement.getAttributeByName(new QName("t"));
      if (type != null && "s".equals(type.getValue())) {
       nextValueIsSharedString = true;
      } else {
       nextValueIsSharedString = false;
      }
     } else if(startElementName.getLocalPart().equalsIgnoreCase("v")) { //start element of value
      row.append("<v>");
      valueFound = true;
     }
    } else if(event.isCharacters() && valueFound) {
     Characters characters = (Characters)event;
     if (nextValueIsSharedString) {
      row.append("shared string: " + characters.getData());
     } else {
      row.append(characters.getData());
     }
    } else if(event.isEndElement()) {
     EndElement endElement = (EndElement)event;
     QName endElementName = endElement.getName();
     if(endElementName.getLocalPart().equalsIgnoreCase("v")) { //end element of value
      row.append("</v>");
      valueFound = false;
     } else if(endElementName.getLocalPart().equalsIgnoreCase("c")) { //end element of cell
      row.append("</c>");
     } else if(endElementName.getLocalPart().equalsIgnoreCase("row")) { //end element of row
      row.append("</row>");
      return row.toString();
     }
    }
   }
   return "No more rows.";
  }

  public void close() throws Exception {
   if (sheetreader != null) sheetreader.close();
   if (opcpackage != null) opcpackage.close();
  }
 }
}
```

For sure this is only a draft to show the principle. The whole application would be much more code.

Next we would have to read and parse the `/xl/sharedStrings.xml` package part, which contains the shared strings. Also we have to read and parse the `/xl/styles.xml` package part which contains the cell styles. We need the styles to detect whether a numeric value is a date or a number and if a number, then what kind of number.  This is necessary because `Excel` stores all kinds of numbers as double values. And dates also are numbers as doubles, meaning days after 01/01/1900 with fractional part as 1h = 1/24, 1m = 1/24/60, 1s = 1/24/60/60.

But this is possible using the same approach as with the `/xl/worksheets/sheetN.xml` package part.

Comment: I appreciate the response, but your solution is way more work than I was looking to take on :) I would still like to figure out something in this area, something more similar to what `XSSFSheetXMLHandler` provides, but for now I've redesigned my solution to work around the limitations.